# Get function value of a instance method in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How do I get the function value `f` of an instance method?

```
class X(i : Int){
    def method(y : Int) = y + i
}

val x = new X(10)
val f : (Int) => Int = ?

val r = x.method(2)
val r2 = f(2)
```

Calling `x.method(2)` and `f(2)` would be the same method call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
scala> class X(i : Int){ def method(y : Int) = y + i }

defined class X

scala> val x = new X(10)

x: X = X@15b28d8

scala> val f = x.method _

f: (Int) => Int = <function>

scala> val r = x.method(2)

r: Int = 12

scala> val r2 = f(2)

r2: Int = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

[this](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html) useful reference indicates that methods don't have functions, functions have methods - however if you wanted to make a function from a method perhaps this is what you want:

```
scala> def m1(x:Int) = x+3
m1: (Int)Int
scala> val f2 = m1 _
f2: (Int) => Int = <function>
```